# Check column for value before insert, if exists move to next field in Access form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have use "E "0000000000a;0;# in input mask and included this code to check if the employeeCode already exists in the Before Update.
But when i am trying to input a duplicate employee code.  It's allowing it.
Any idea?

```
Private Sub Empl_Code_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   If IsNull(DLookup("[EmplCode]", _
   "FORM EMPLOYEE", _
   "[EmplCode] = """ & Me.Empl_Code.Text & """")) = False Then
      Cancel = True
      MsgBox "Record already exists", vbOKOnly, "Warning" 
      Me![Empl Code].Undo
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like VBA code, so don't use `.Text` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks legit.
Test your *IsNull(DLookup...* expression in Immediate window (View - Immediate window in VBA Editor) when you are trying to input a duplicate code.
Also you can shorten a bit your expression with DCount like that:

```vb
Private Sub Empl_Code_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   If DCount("*", _
   "FORM EMPLOYEE", _
   "[EmplCode] = """ & Me.Empl_Code.Text & """") > 0 Then
      Cancel = True
      MsgBox "Record already exists", vbOKOnly, "Warning" 
      Me![Empl Code].Undo
   else
      ' Just for test
      MsgBox "Value: " & Me.Empl_Code.Text
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: does adding an input mask  "E "0000000000a;0;# has any implications to that beforeUpdate code?

Comment: As I know there is no implications for VBA. Did you tried my code?

Comment: ok getting run time error 3075 @ If DLookup("*", _
"FORMS EMPLOYEE", _
"[EmplCode] = """ & Me.Empl_Code.Text & """") > 0 Then

Comment: DCount, not DLookup

Comment: i get value as 'E 12000000023_ ' on the screen and when click on OK it save the duplicate record ... any idea?

Comment: So if "E 12000000023_" is not like something you want to get try again without input mask.

Comment: without input mask it's working.. I'm getting the message record exists.  but I've added the input mask as I want that the first character start wz E followed by space and then some number to b entered the last digit should be optional.. is there another way to do so? or vba code for tht input mask ?